# Java recursive method for counting words

Tags: java, recursion, count, words

I should first of all say this is an assignment that is confusing me, I've already corrected one of the questions by the lecturer :/

Anyway, I've made a method which counts the words using booleans, a while loop and a counter.

However I need to some how shape this into a recursive method that counts the amount of words in a string, a word is delimited by one or many spaces.

`countWords("  hello   this  is   an example", 0); // returns 5`

As you can see the only parameters are countWords(String s, int i) making it more difficult.

Also, within the method I'm restricted to only using these three methods s.charAt(0), s.substring(1) and s.equals("") again making it more of a head hurter :)

This is the none recursive method I wrote using a while loop:

```
public static int countWords(String s) {
    int words = 0;
    boolean spaceBefore = true;
    boolean spaceCurrently = false;
    while(true) {
        if (s.equals(""))
            return words;

        if (s.charAt(0) == ' ')
            spaceCurrently = true;
        else
            spaceCurrently = false;

        if (spaceBefore && !spaceCurrently)
            words++;        

        spaceBefore = spaceCurrently;
        s = s.substring(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your first method. And whatever code you have tried for your recursive one.

Comment: Hints: number of words = number of spaces +1. Number of words = 1 + number of words in the String after the first space.

Comment: @MrSmith42 `a word is delimited by one or **many** spaces`

Comment: Posted method as requested by Mr Spoon

Comment: @fvu: Ok but that does not change the algorithm idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since this is a homework assignment, I'll refrain from giving you the code. But I'll explain the solution to you. See if you can rebuild the code from it.

In the method, first remove the white spaces from the beginning and end of the line since we want to ignore it. Use the `trim()` method for that. Next check if the string is an empty string (`""`) like you did in the code. If it is, then return a zero because an empty string contains no words, otherwise in an infinite loop (`while (true)`) check the following conditions:

- Create a variable to hold the current index, one which is not local to the loop, but it local to the method. For each iteration of the infinite loop, check if the current character (using the `charAt()` method) is not a space and that the index is less than the length of the string. If this condition is true, increment the index variable.
- If not, check if the index variable is equal to the length of the string. If yes, then return a 1, because it means that we have reached the last word of the string.
- If not, return the sum of 1 and the method to count words, recursively called for the substring from the current value of index.

This should get you the value. If you are still unable to do it, let me know and I'll give you the source.

**EDIT** Well if you cannot use String's trim method, you can write one for yourself like this. I believe it does not violate any of your requirements:

```
private String trim(String str) {
    int beginIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = str.length() - 1;

    while (true) {
        if (str.charAt(beginIndex) == ' ') {
            beginIndex++;
        } else if (str.charAt(endIndex) == ' ') {
            endIndex--;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return str.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
}
```

**Edit 2** If you cannot use `length()` either, then modify the above line of code `int endIndex = str.length() - 1;' to`int endIndex = getLength(str) - 1;` and use the following code for calculating length.

```
private int getLength(String str) {
    int length = 0;

    while (true) {
        try {
            str.charAt(length++);
        } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return --length;
}
```

**Edit 3** Since the question is such a PITA, it would be difficult to explain in words. So here's the code:

```
private int countWords(String searchString) {
    int index = 0;
    boolean beginning = true;       // to check if it's the beginning of the line

    if (searchString.equals("")) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (searchString.charAt(index) != ' ') {
                    beginning = false;
                    index++;
                } else {
                    if (!beginning) {
                        return 1 + countWords(searchString.substring(++index));
                    } else {
                        return countWords(searchString.substring(++index));
                    }
                }
            } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                if (!beginning) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This would help you achieve what you want with only the methods you are allowed to use.

Comment: I cannot use the trim() method.

Comment: You can use the above code if you don't want to use `String`'s `trim()`.

Comment: I can't use .length() either lol, I specifically said I can only use the three methods stated in my question?

Comment: Though I wholeheartedly believe that using `length()` must have been allowed, I have edited my solution to incorporate your request.

Comment: Lol, my lecturer is extremely picky and wants us to get to the core of not using any API methods other than the three I said, we are also not allowed to calculate the length of the String XD

Comment: @Ciphor Are you kidding me?

Comment: No sadly not, I could easily do this if I could use other methods XD We are strictly forbidden to only use the three I stated and cannot create our own length() method.

Comment: None of your solutions would be accepted, you can see why I came to here now :p

Comment: Pray tell me why the last one won't be accepted? IT fulfils all your criteria as far as I can see.

Comment: You've updated it since and it looks fine, although I actually managed to do it myself now in a slightly different way but this will be the accepted answer, it's good :)

Answer (score 0):

I won't post code directly as this is your assignment but here are some directions.

Number of words in the string is the current word + number of words in the rest of the string.
Since you are limited to processing one char at the time you can think of it this way:

- have a parameter that tells you if you are in a word
- if s.charAt(0) is a space and you are in a word then you will increase the counter and set inWord to false
- if s.charAt(0) is a letter and you are not in a word then you set inWord to true
- recurse with updated counter and s.subString(1) and updated inWord

and you kick off everything with 0, s, false

Imagine converting a loop to recursion as moving your variables from outside of loop into method parameters.

I hope this wasn't too confusing.

Comment: I can't have a boolean as a parameter though.

Comment: you need to hold your state somewhere if you can only move one character at a time. If you can assert that there will only be only one space between words you don't need state.

Comment: That's the trouble, if I try and create a boolean within the method it will always be reset back to what I originally set it too, I need a way of working with the reset.

Answer (score 0):

Given this is homework, I won't give you the answer straight off.

Recursion if a mechanism where a method calls itself.  Obviously if a method does this indefinately you'll eventually get a stackoverflow exception, so you need some sort of exit condition where the method stops calling itself.

Here's an example - imagine you wanted to write a multiplication method that takes two numbers and multiplies them but you only have addition and subtraction at your disposal.

```
public int multiply(int value1, int value2) 
{
  if (value1 > 1) 
  {
    int remaining = value1 - 1;
    return value2 + multiply(remaining, value2);
  }
  else 
  {
    return value2;
  }
}
```

Here the method calls itself until it's added the `value2` to itself `value1` times at which point it returns up the stack.

You can do something similiar with your word counting - keep calling the method passing a sub-string taken from the first space to the end of the string until there are no more spaces in the string at which point return up the stack.